# Как сериализованный java объект сохранить в couchbase?

Tags: java

Есть сериализованный объект java, как объект записать в couchbase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Желательно бы знать, в какой формат объект был сериализован. Оптимальнее всего сериализовать объект в JSON, тогда Couchbase сможет не только хранить его, но и индексировать для запросов N1QL, полнотекстового поиска или MapReduce views.

Для JSON есть удобные классы в самой библиотеке, например [JsonDocument](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.5.5/com/couchbase/client/java/document/JsonDocument.html):

```
JsonObject arthur = JsonObject.create()
        .put("name", "Arthur")
        .put("email", "kingarthur@couchbase.com")
        .put("interests", JsonArray.from("Holy Grail", "African Swallows"));
bucket.upsert(JsonDocument.create("u:king_arthur", arthur));
```

Но если в общем случае, объект сериализован в массив байт, то лучше использовать [ByteArrayDocument](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.5.5/com/couchbase/client/java/document/ByteArrayDocument.html):

```
double[] telemetry = new double[]{0.12, 0.24, 0.56};

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
oos.writeObject(telemetry);
oos.flush();

bucket.upsert(ByteArrayDocument.create("telemetry:42", baos.toByteArray()));
```

Но, ещё раз повторю, сервер Couchbase ничего не знает о способе, которым сериализован документ (если это не JSON) и не сможет его проиндексировать для запросов или поиска.

Comment: Как вариант, можно ведь создать класс-обертку, в одном из полей будет id, другое поле data будет хранить массив сериализованных байтов. Что в таком случае, обертку лучше всего положить как JSONObject? После прочтения из базы у меня будет тот же набор байтов, с которыми я положил туда свой объект?

Comment: Так тоже можно, но в этом случае так же нужно учесть, что JSON не позволяет нативно передать байты, и тот массив сериализованных байтов нужно будет дополнительно экранировать, при записи в строку или кодировать в base64, что дополнительно раздует общий объём документа.

Answer (score 0):

Владислав, не совсем по теме, но возможно это поможет в написании приложений на java под Couchbase: через клиентские библиотеки можно создавать структуры данных Map, List, Queue и Set.  Вот страница с документацией: [Data Structures](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/java/datastructures.html)